# Identity management/SSO solution?

Tags: single-sign-on, identity, user-management, josso

What are your recommendations for a basic, centralized identity management/SSO service? It must be open source, have a pluggable identity manager (eg: LDAP, DB, openID, etc.) and provide a decent range of API access options (eg: web services, REST, etc.).  It must also be clusterable for high availability.

JOSSO? CAS? others?

Comment: I've been doing alot of SSO work lately and it seems that Sun Access Manager / OpenSSO seems to be the most popular although I have found OpenSSO to be a PIA. I am looking forward to MS's Geneva Framework for .net http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa570351.aspx currently in beta.

Comment: When you say "it must be open source" do you mean the source code must be provided or it must be free (as in beer)?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of open source SSO solutions, [OpenAM/OpenSSO](http://forgerock.com/openam.html), [CAS Server](http://www.jasig.org/cas) and [Shibboleth](http://shibboleth.internet2.edu/).

Answer (score 0):

Dont forguet [simpleSAMLphp](http://simplesamlphp.org/) if you looking for SAML support or [HybridAuth](http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/) if you just looking for a SSO library.

Answer (score 0):

[WSO2](http://wso2.com/products/identity-server/) as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14521397/forgerock-identity-management-solution-vs-wso2-identity-server). It's absolutely free, Java based and integrates with most of services / apps via various protocols or APIs.

Comment: We've been evaluating WSO2 and it's proven to be a bit hard to get it up and running. Presumably, support is where the revenue comes from so take this into account when thinking it's free.