# Best solution for centralised identity management

Tags: single-sign-on, cas, josso, openidm

I am investigating an open source solution for IdM.

So far, my choices are `OpenIDM`, `OpenAM`, `Josso` & `CAS`.

But most solutions are focusing on `SSO`, however my requirements are more on user management and provisioning. Can `Josso/CAS/OpenIDM` provide user provisioning/deprovisioning, group policy , etc? Any open source alternative to `Atlassian Crowd`, matching in every functionality?

Comment: This question is also very similar:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/780490/identity-management-sso-solution

Answer (score 0):

The open source solutions that you mention focus largely on SSO, not identity management. JOSSO has a user provisioning feature but AFAIK it does not include group policies. If you are looking for a full identity management solution you would need to look at the commercial products like [Cloudseal](http://www.cloudseal.com), [Crowd](http://www.atlassian.com/software/crowd/overview), Oracle etc.